# How to search for Case by CaseNumber in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In Salesforce, every Case has a unique CaseNumber that is set by the system when the Case is created.  The content is an autonumber with a display format, such as {00000000}.  This display format can be modified by the system administrator.

For example Case #144 will have a CaseNumber = 00000144.
Case #12345678 will have CaseNumber = 12345678.

Users refer to Cases by number; without the leading zeros. So, I need to find the Case by searching for case number.

Suppose the user wants case #145?  This search will not find any results:

```
Case matchingCase = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where CaseNumber = '145'];
```

Suppose I can assume the displayFormat for CaseNumber never changes.  In this case I could prepend leading zeros to make a query that works. For example, if the display format for CaseNumber is {00000000} then this query works:

```
Case matchingCase = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where CaseNumber = '00000145'];
```

But the display format can be changed so we can't assume anything.

Question 1. Using some API query how can we query to obtain the displayFormat to determine the number of leading zeros?

The alternative approach is to use LIKE.  For example this "works"

```
Case[] matchingCases = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where CaseNumber LIKE '%145'];
```

BUT the query returns all cases that end in 145 including cases like '00009145'.

Question(2) How can I form a query to return exactly case number 145?

Comment: Regarding question (1) I already checked the "manual" on the sObject describe field and it doesn't mention display format. See [http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm)

Answer (score 2):

After posting this question I wondered if I could build a SOQL query that converted CaseNumber String to Integer?

```
Case[] matchingCases = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where Integer.valueOf(CaseNumber) = 144];
```

But there is no support for this in SOQL.

Yet this bit of code works because it tests based on Integer comparison.

```
Integer target = 144;
String caseNumber = '%' + String.valueOf(target);
Case[] matchingCases = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where CaseNumber like :caseNumber];
for(Case aCase: matchingCases)
{
  Integer cnum = Integer.valueOf(aCase.CaseNumber);
  if(cnum == target) {
    system.debug('FOUND IT');
    break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I've posted the above in a complete Apex class that replaces the default Salesforce Email-to-Case handler.  See http://sforcehacks.blogspot.com/2012/01/email-to-case-can-create-too-many-cases.html   Look for the method called locateByCaseNumberAsString

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is by using SOSL instead of SOQL. For example, the below works.

```
Integer iCaseNumber = 28;
String sCaseNumber = (iCaseNumber!=null?'*'+String.valueOf(iCaseNumber):'');

List<List<Case>> matchingCases = 
    [FIND :sCaseNumber RETURNING Case (Id, CaseNumber, Subject Order By CaseNumber)];

system.debug(matchingCases);
```

SOSL has different [execution governor limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), though. As of right now, only 20 can be executed per Apex call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in having those leading zeros. It's a throwback to *really* old systems that were too stupid to not print the zeros. I suggest you remove the zeros from the format.

Comment: How?  This display format is set in the salesforce default instance.  Once a case is created they CaseNumber field can not (should not) be modified.

Comment: I keep thinking about this issue.. You could create a Custom Field to convert the CaseNumber to an Integer, then query off of that.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing your query, create a variable for the CaseNumber and pad it with zeros.

```
Case LargestCaseNumber = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description FROM Case ORDER BY CaseNumber DESC LIMIT 1];
Integer MaxCaseNumber = (LargestCaseNumber!=null?LargestCaseNumber.CaseNumber.length():8);

Integer iCaseNumber = 145;
String sCaseNumber = (iCaseNumber!=null?String.valueOf(iCaseNumber):'');
for(Integer i=sCaseNumber.length(); i<MaxCaseNumber; i++) { sCaseNumber='0'+sCaseNumber; }

Case[] matchingCases = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Description from Case where CaseNumber = :sCaseNumber];

system.debug(matchingCases);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. But, how do we know to pad it with 8 zeros?  The SF instance may have a different display format for CaseNumber.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to get the DisplayFormat or the DisplayFormat length.

Comment: I modified the answer to check for the LargestCaseNumber. This probably could be done with an Aggregate Query, but it seems ORDER BY is faster. That should get you the maximum length for the data. However, there's still the concern that if the DisplayFormat was one length in the past, there will be some records with less leading zeros. It appears that there's not an easy way around it.